# What is difference between initilizing an NSString simply and with retain?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management

I want to know that difference between following two lines

```
 name1 = [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,1)] retain];

 name1 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,1)];
```

What will be effect on name1 if I do use retain at the last,

I face once problem, and couldn't use name1 in a method that is being call by NSTimer, and when I use retain, they it worked fine for me.

If I do call value from database in viewDidLoad, and use in a method that is being called by NSTimer after each second, then it will give bad-exec, but when I do use retain then it will work properly,

I want to know the reason

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html

Comment: @Zneak, I know the retain will increase count +1, but what is reason for such behavior?

Comment: Please [take some time and read past the introduction](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-SW1). Your program crashes because you use a method on a freed object, and your object is freed because no one took ownership of it by the time your timer code is run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the difference

```
- (void)func1 {
    name1 = [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:...] retain];
    name2 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:...];
}

- (void)func2 {
    NSLog(@"%@", name1);    //OK, name1 is still there
    NSLog(@"%@", name2);    //Would be crashed because name2 could be released anytime after func1 is finished.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this answer to another question, but it explains what you're asking:

Objects in objective c have a retain count. If this retain count is greater that 0 when the object goes out of scope (when you stop using it), it leaks.

The following things increase the retain count

```
[[alloc] init]
new
copy
[retain]
adding an object to an array
adding an object as a child (e.g. views)
There are likely more, but you don't appear to use any others in your code
```

The following decrease the retain count

```
[release]
removing an object from an array
if you dealloc an array, all of its objects are released
```

You should go through your code and ensure each of the retains or additions to an array are matched with a corresponding release. (You can release member variables in the dealloc method).

Another user made a valid point that my answer doesn't

> Once you add an object to an array, it takes ownership and will release the object when it is done with it. All you need to do is make sure you release anything you own according to the memory management rules

There are also autorelease objects, have a look at this example;

```
-(init){
    ...
    stagePickerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        //this string is autoreleased, you don't have call release on it.
        //methods with the format [CLASS CLASSwithsomething] tend to be autorelease
        NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i);
        [stagePickerArray addObject:s];
    }
    ...
 }
```

Your issue is that when you come to use your string later, it has a retain count of zero and has been released. By calling retain on it, you're saying 'I want to use this later'. Don't forget to match every retain with a release or you're objects will 'leak'

Comment: but when you are assigning the value in name1 and can use in any body, but except in method that is being called by time, I did solution either call method (the fetching method that is taking value from db and saving to name1) in within method that is being called by timer, else use retain, but can't understand the reason, can you explain it

Answer (score 1):

I bet your code wouldn't crash if your `name1` was a property - either `(nonatomic, retain)` or just `(copy)` depending on your needs.

Second condition is to have `name1` initialized to sth meaningful at the time your other function tries to do sth with it.

**EDIT:**
With a property you'd have to use synthesized setter in this case with: `self.name1 = @"your string";`.
Normally you don't have to manually retain/release a string created with `stringWith...` methods since there's nothing you created in memory yourself by using explicit `alloc`. Also please note that with code:
`NSString *str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:@"your string"];`
your `str` (if not used to set a property) will stop being available when the function gets out of scope (iOS eventloop will autorelease it).